# Fedora 30 : Ensure No Device Files are Unlabeled by SELinux

Tags: fedora, devices, selinux, hardening

While hardening Fedora 30, I encountered this measure on [open-scap.org](https://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-fedora-guide-ospp.html#xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_selinux_all_devicefiles_labeled) and actually the command :

```
sudo find /dev -context *:device_t:* \( -type c -o -type b \) -printf "%p %Z\n"
```

returns on my system :

```
/dev/udmabuf system_u:object_r:device_t:s0
```

Is /dev/udmabuf labelled correctly or not please ?

Comment: It looks like it's labeled correctly.

Comment: I thought so but was not sure : Thanks !